# Preserve citation links in PDF export document from MS word document

Tags: pdf, ms-word, citations

I want to export a word document to a pdf document with working links.

All links such as cross-reference to another section work in the pdf document. Only the citation links which point to the bibliography at the end of the document get lost during the export.

I use the citavi add-on in word to create the citation links and the bibliography.

I already tried saving the word document as pdf and exporting it.

Is there a way to preserve those citation links?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The not working links are related to the Citavi Add-in.

First you have to activate "Link in-text citations to references in the bibliography" under "Options" in the Citavi Add-in Tab in Word.

Then under "Convert" you can click "Save a copy as static text (with hyperlinks)".

After this just save the document as pdf and the links are adopted in the pdf document.