# Citavi hyperlinks not linked to bibliography entry in PDF but as Sharepoint-links

Tags: ms-word, citations

I have the problem that my citations in the text are not linked to the bibliography after generating a PDF from a MS Word file. I'm using the Citavi Word Add-In.

I have already activated the checkbox "Link references in text to bibliography" and then updated the document using the "Refresh" button. I can then use Ctrl + mouse button left to jump to the respective reference in the bibliography. However, as soon as I generate the PDF (even if "Convert Citavi fields to text (incl. hyperlinks)" has been executed beforehand), the links always take me to my Sharepoint page in the Internet browser.

Can anyone help me here?

I saw this post [1] but as described, the procedure didn't help me with problem.

[1] [Preserve citation links in PDF export document from MS word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729245/preserve-citation-links-in-pdf-export-document-from-ms-word-document)

Edit: The hyperlink contains both, the file path (e.g.:"https://XXXX-my.sharepoint.com/personal/) including the file name and the Citavi key (e.g.:"#_CTVL001e82b9...").